# Trying to edit a ms word document and save as a pdfusing django

Tags: python-3.x, django, ms-word

I want to read data from a ms excel file and edit an existing words document using the data from excel to fill in bookmarks and then save it as a pdf. So far I have been able to read to data successfully using openpyxl but I'm struggling with the editing and saving part.  It would be great if someone can help.

my code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import openpyxl
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
import io
from io import BytesIO


def index(request):
    if "GET" == request.method:
        return render(request, 'letters/index.html', {})
    else:
        excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]

        # you may put validations here to check extension or file size

        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)

        # getting a particular sheet by name out of many sheets
        worksheet = wb.sheetnames
        if 'sheet name' in wb.sheetnames:
            sheet = wb['sheet name']
        print(worksheet)

        excel_data = list()
        # iterating over the rows and
        # getting value from each cell in row
        for name in wb.sheetnames:
            sheet = wb[name]
            first = False
            for row in sheet.iter_rows():
                row_data = list()
                for cell in row:
                    row_data.append(str(cell.value))
                print (row_data)
                
                if first == False:
                    pass
                else:
                    buffer = io.BytesIO()
                    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
                    f = open("media/template.docx", "w+")
                    for x in range (5):
                        def BookMarkReplace():
                            f.Bookmark = name, 
                            string = row_data[0])
                        {
                        Admission = row_data[2]
                        p.drawString(doc)
                        p.showPage()
                        p.save()
                        response ['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=Admission.docx'
                        return response
                first = True
                excel_data.append(row_data)
               
    return render(request, 'letters/index.html', {"excel_data":excel_data})
```

I'm not having any luck with this method. Does anyone know how to do this or any other way of doing this.

Comment: doc.save('Admission.docx')

Comment: @SANGEETHSUBRAMONIAM the didn't get saved in my media file. Do you know how I can save it as word or PDF

Comment: Sorry haven't worked with py-docx... But you are assigning a string value to the variable Admission, So you cannot use .docx because the compiler reads .docx as a method call rather than a extension

Comment: check if this helps https://avleonov.com/2017/12/02/processing-docx-and-xlsx-files-with-python/

Comment: Ohh thankyou @SANGEETHSUBRAMONIAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!!!
I used python-doxc to edit my word documents. I still couldn'f figure out how to use bookmarks, but instead I replaced the parts I want to edit like so:

```
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
  if 'Name of the student   : ' in paragraph.text:
     paragraph.text = 'Name of the student  : ' + Name
```

Then I used pypandoc to covnvert them to pdfs.

```
pypandoc.convert_file('template.docx', 'pdf', outputfile='S' + ' ' + Name + '.pdf')
```